# XSLT position of chosen elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to display position of chosen nodes.

xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:call-template name="Convert"></xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:template name="Convert">
        <Pos>
            <Type><xsl:value-of select="type"/></Type>
            <LineNumber><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></LineNumber>
            ...
        </Pos>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My xml is:

```
<OrderPositions>
    <Pos>
         <Type>simple</Type>
         <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
         ...
    </Pos>
    <Pos>
         <Type>complex</Type>
         <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
         ...
    </Pos>
    <Pos>
         <Type>simple</Type>
         <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
         ...
    </Pos>
    <Pos>
         <Type>complex</Type>
         <LineNumber>4</LineNumber> 
         ...
    </Pos>
</OrderPositions>
```

Trying to exclude "*complex*" types in xslt using `<xsl:choose>` + `<xsl:when test="type='simple'">` gives **LineNumber** 1,3,5,7 etc. What is the proper way to choose only "*simple*" (remove "*complex*") types and display it positions like 1,2,3,4 etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy all nodes over to the output by default using the identity transformation, modified to suppress complex `Pos` elements and output `LineNumber` elements with values set to the **count of all preceding simple `Pos` elements**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Pos[Type = 'complex']"/>

  <xsl:template match="LineNumber">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::Pos[Type = 'simple']) + 1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Then your output will be:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderPositions>
  <Pos>
      <Type>simple</Type>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    ...
  </Pos>

  <Pos>
      <Type>simple</Type>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
    ...
  </Pos>

</OrderPositions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#number)...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Pos[Type='complex']"/>

    <xsl:template match="LineNumber">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:number count="Pos[Type='simple']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```